# How to get consuming project's namespace at source generation postinitialization step?

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I'm building my Incremental Source Generator project to explore this new tool.

I'm on the verge to refine it as it work for now.

One thing I want to improve is to change the namespace of my auto-generated marker attribute used by consuming projects.

For now namespace are hard coded in the string representation of the code to be generated.

For example:

```
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
{            
    context.RegisterPostInitializationOutput
        (@context =>
        {
            @context.AddSource("SettableNTimesProperty.g.cs", SourcesAsString.GetSettableNTimesCode());
            @context.AddSource("SetNTimesAttribute.g.cs", SourcesAsString.GetSetNTimesAttributeCode());
        });

    var pipeline = context.SyntaxProvider    
        .CreateSyntaxProvider(SourcesAsString.SyntacticPredicate, SourcesAsString.SemanticTransform)
        .Where(found => found is not null && found.HasValue)
        .Collect()
        .Select(SourcesAsString.TransformType)
        ;

    context.RegisterSourceOutput(pipeline, SourcesAsString.Execute);
}
```

and

```
public static string GetSetNTimesAttributeCode()
{
    return
        @"
    // <auto-generated/>

    namespace SetOnceProperties.Sources.Utilities.Attributes
    {
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
        internal class SetNTimesAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public int MaximumSettable { get; }

            public SetNTimesAttribute(int maximumSettable = 1)
            {
                MaximumSettable = maximumSettable;
            }
        }

        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false)]
        internal sealed class SetOnceAttribute : SetNTimesAttribute
        { }
    }";
}
```

I know how to get the namespace while I'm on the "pipeline" steps using `xxxDeclarationSyntax` parameter.

But for the `RegisterPostInitializationOutput` step, I only have access to the `IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext` parameter, from which I don't know how to retrieve consuming projects namespace.

Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the short answer is that this is not possible. The `GeneratePostInitializationOutput` method receives no inputs about the compilation by design.

However, not all hope is lost. I happened to have a similar problem where I wanted certain simple marker classes and attributes to be generated in the correct namespace, but also be available during semantic analysis for the rest of the generator.

The way I solved this definitely feels like a hack, so use with caution, but it is as follows:

You create the source outputs for the markers using `RegisterSourceOutput`, so you have full access to the compilation to fetch the namespace.
Then you manually create an updated compilation within a new `IncrementalValueProvider`.
Then the rest of the generator should use that provider.

```cs
public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context) {
    context.RegisterSourceOutput(context.CompilationProvider, SourceAsString.Execute);

    IncrementalValueProvider<Compilation> compilationProvider = context.CompilationProvider.Select(
        (compilation, cancelToken) => {
            string source = SourceAsString.Execute(compilation);
            SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source, (CSharpParseOptions)compilation.SyntaxTrees.First().Options);
            return compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
        }
    );
}
```

You're essentially just generating the attribute twice, once as an actual source output, and once as an additional syntax tree in the compilation provider.

One thing to note is that this is specifically acting on the CompilationProvider, not the SyntaxProvider, since that was the use-case I used this in.
You can probably do something very similar for the syntax provider, but that is left as an exercise for the reader.

I'll repeat, use with caution. I literally just came up with this workaround yesterday. I have no idea whether this will break at some point, or what the impacts on performance are.